# How much data is needed to compare different datasets and get a significant result

Tags: statistical-significance

if I have several datasets and each element in those sets is either A or B (which means I'll get an A/B proportion for each dataset at the end), how many elements should be in each set so that the comparison at the end may tell me whether there are any statistically significant results?

I feel like this is really simple (and that I should know this from highschool) but I seem to have forgotten the right terms because my googling gave me all sorts of answers but not what I need.
Anyone care to help a clueless fellow?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a simple, "high school" level question. First of all, the description of the problem is not clear, at least to me, as I can think of several ways in which these datasets can be arranged to form a test.

It sounds like you have several *sources* of data and want to perform a Type 1 test of group differences in *proportions* based on a ratio of A and B. The conventional, stats 101 answer to this is that you need 30 data points in each dataset to obtain a "meaningful" test. However, as is known from statistical testing in human clinical trials, e.g., in pharma, "meaningful" tests can be done with samples as small as 5 or 6 patients. The issue is that the standard errors forming the basis of the test are a function of the sample size. So, the smaller the sample size, the larger the standard errors which makes it harder to reach "significance".

The more important question is concerned with Type 2 tests of statistical power. Tests of power answer the question whether or not you have enough information (data) to test for significance, given a pre-specified probability level. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power

> (Power) can be equivalently thought of as the probability of accepting the
>   alternative hypothesis (H1) when it is true—that is, the ability of a
>   test to detect an effect, if the effect actually exists.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I have datasets for a certain timespan and if need be, I could increase the timespan to obtain more data. But first I have to now if the amount of data I have collected thus far could already end up being useful. I see in my stats manual that power tests depend on effect size, which depends on explained variance calculated by r, which in turn depends on the t test. So... how do I perform a t-test and how do I go on from there?

Comment: Given that you have data the variance can be empirically, not theoretically, obtained. More typically, tests of power begin with a threshold of probability above which you assume you have adequate power to evaluate the Type 1 hypothesis. One commonly used convention or rule of thumb is to assume 80% as the minimum for this. Effect size can be plugged in using a stepwise or matrix form assuming various levels for each, e.g., for effect size, choose meaningful values that start small and step up through a range of possibilities to some reasonable maximum level.